# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spriteUtils'

Tags: python

In my code, it says IndexError: list index out of range
Im a bit confused on whats wrong

```
 import sys, os, math
from superwires import games
from spriteUtils import *

filename = sys.argv[1]
x = int(sys.argv[2])
y = int(sys.argv[3])

games.init(screen_width = 1024, screen_height = 768, fps = 50)

class Character(games.Animation):
    yelp = games.load_sound(os.path.join('sounds', 'yahoo-1.wav'))
    laugh = games.load_sound(os.path.join('sounds', 'crowd-laughing.wav'))
    STEP = 4
    FLOOR = 0
    GRAVITY = 0.25
    POP = -12
```

Comment: So what is expected here? Title is module not found error but the question differs from it.

Comment: @ML_Enthu Whats expected is that it is supposed to take a sprite list and run the animation for it

Comment: the only place where IndexError can occur in this code is the sys.argv. Are you sure you are passing expected arguments to your script?